# How to launch firefox browser from Internet Explorer hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, firefox, hyperlink, cross-browser

My requirement is to open Firefox browser by default from Internet Explorer.

I have made a hyperlink in JSP page which is opened in Internet Explorer.

On click of this hyperlink, that URL should open directly in Firefox instead of a new tab in IE.

For Example:
[google link](http://www.google.com) this hyperlink is currently in IE JSP page, on click of this it should open in Firefox.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't write a question and disappear. You need to accept/vote for correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can not dictate which browser to use via hyperlink. It is totally up to user. Internet browsers have no API for that job. It would be a huge security risk to launch an app via hyperlink.